# Is there a way to match coordinates from 2D sheets to 3D view for an item?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I work on forge viewer to display Revit converted files. I try to put points into 2D sheets view that I would then display into 3D view. (e.g. in revit red house sample file, from sheet "A-102 plans" to 3D view {3D} ).

Currently, I see only something like:

- From 2D view:

  - Extract coordinates of point from 2D view relatively to item 2d-bouding-box
  - Convert these relative coordinates into a x,y,z ratio to the size of the item (plus solve from x,y,z, what are the 2 axes we see in 2D)
- Into 3D view:

  - Get 3D bounding box of the item
  - Compute point position from previous info

Since coordinates are different between the 2 views (which sounds expected), is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm looking into it. Since it might take time to investigate, I will right back once I have a solution for you.

Comment: Since the coordinate systems of both 2D and 3D views in Forge Viewer are different, we will need a bounding box of the 2D viewport in Revit Sheet for coordinate conversion, see [viewer-navigation.sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-navigation.sample/blob/master/www/scripts/marker.js) for details. However, there are some missing connections between Revit 2D sheets and Forge 2D views which are mentioned in [rac.json](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-navigation.sample/blob/master/www/rac.json), so I'm checking with our team if they have some insights.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it makes a first track to explore.